# Chrome redraw issue

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm getting an odd redraw issue in chrome:

[image: Screenshot]

See the broken right side? This is a `div` with a single background `img`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="resultsSortFilter>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#resultsSortFilter {
    float: left;
    width: 712px;
    height: 109px;
    margin: 7px 0 0 8px;
    background: url('../images/search_sortfilter_bg.png') no-repeat;
}
```

- No issues in any other browser
- Happens on newer versions only, we blocked the update to prevent this causing issues internally.
- Seems to be triggered by scrolling up and down before rendering is finished.
- Same issues on multiple sites

Has anyone else seen this? Anybody knows what's causing it or what Chrome intends to do about it?

Chrome version `26.0.1410.64 m`

**Update**

The issue is on Windows and Mac OS. In fact seems worse on Mac.

I might have pinned it down further. We get the error on a page that contains lots of large images. I'm wondering if it has to do with the size of the data Chrome has to download?

This appears to make the issue go away (not going to call it a fix):

> "It might be that the newer version of Chrome simply does not like
>   your GPU. I have had issues similar to yours and have solved them by
>   turning off the compositing and 3D acceleration features.
>
> Type
>   chrome://flags into the address bar and set the following items:
>
> - GPU compositing on all pages: Disabled (Three options in a drop-down.)
> - Disable accelerated 2D canvas: Enable (Click the link that says
>     'Enable', the box will turn white.)
> - Disable accelerated CSS
>     animations: Enable (Like above, the item will turn white.)
> - Then click
>     the button that shows up at the bottom of the page Relaunch now to
>     restart chrome and test if this worked."

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/167140/google-chrome-with-strange-behavior

### Update

The issue seems to be gone in later versions of Chrome.

Comment: What's your OS?  Have you seen this problem on other operating systems?

Comment: Windows 7. Not 100% sure. Will check!

Comment: Realistiscally impossible for us to debug or analyze without a working example.

Comment: I remember having some problems like this after I did some animations with content in Google Chrome. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes#answer-3485654) shows how to force a "redraw" in Webkit browsers, which solved my problem.

Comment: No animations on the page, it's static content.

Comment: @Liam Did you try the answer given there? It maybe still helps you.

Comment: @w4rumy I don't think this is a practical solution. I'd have to run that javascript on every image on my page!

Comment: What happens when you run the site in incognito?

Comment: @Bondye same issue.....:/

Comment: mmm, are you able to share a link with us? :D Or create something simular in a fiddle?

Comment: @Bondye no sorry, can't reproduce in fiddle and sites behind firewall

Comment: Do you have any addon installed?

Comment: Hi. I'm web developer too and I'm suffering several repaint issues on Chrome too since las weeks. In many cases this happens when toggling display: none/block in an element, so the workaround I've found is play with the clip property. But issues appear in many other situations in which I can't achieve a solution... :(

Comment: Yep, chrome is getting buggier every day

Comment: Another relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152470/chrome-rendering-issue-fixed-position-anchor-with-ul-in-body - I opted for `transform: scale3d(1,1,1);`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Chrome is getting buggier. Something worth trying is forcing gpu hardware acceleration on the element.

Add this to the CSS to force hardware acceleration:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry in the delay in getting back. It's taken me a while to get some time to look into this issue again. I'm not sure if this resolved the issue. One thing it did do though is break all of my Jquery UI modal popups?! this applies to the fix suggested by @hoffmann also

Comment: This worked to solve my redraw issue. This also worked:
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002195/chrome-does-not-redraw-div-after-it-is-hidden

Comment: if you transform in the Z plane (3d) the flicker seems to resolve itself

Comment: Thank you. It helped avoiding a strange zoom effect on images only occuring on Chrome, but not Safari.

Answer (score 9):

I have had problems with this in webkit browsers, not only Chrome.
I solved it by placing the following rule on my CSS:

```
html *:not(svg) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); /*only in IE10*/
}
```

This applies hardware acceleration on all elements except for svgs on FF/IE/Safari/Chrome if supported.

I do not apply the transformation on SVG tags since for some reason this was causing my svgs to not render properly, oddly applying this to the elements like rect inside the tag itself causes no problems.

So try to add this rule to your css and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Be careful, as this might cause mobile browsers with little RAM to crash.

Comment: This turns everything into a "composite layer". If you use the performance tools you'll see how this slows down your browser.

Comment: I needed to set it on both element and its children but not everything. Use the "Paint flashing" tool in Chrome to see what elements need a "composite layer".

Answer (score 4):

I have had this kind of issue when toggling `display:none;` `display:block;`

For example with `jQuery.toggle()`

The element in question was just a wrapper for the content I wanted to show and hide. So this is its parent which would expand or shrink vertically. It would look like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-to-toggle">
    </div>
</div>
```

child-to-toggle had no styling rules and, when hidden, a part of the parent wasn't redrawn correctly. (the bottom part)

Then, I added a css rule to child-to-toggle and the problem was solved. It looks like adding a css rule will force some redrawing in that case.

Despite the accepted answer, I am adding this one because enabling hardware acceleration on my computer, Macbook pro, OSX Maverick, Chrome 36, would completely mess up the UI with artefacts so I had to find another way.

Adding a css rule might help. In my case I added a border-top to child-to-toggle.

Comment: In case of the postman UI, the redraw issue was not when we were toggling or operating on the DOM in any way. It was happening when the content inside the element was expanding or contracting due to user interaction. For that we had very little control of triggering a CSS related change.