# Chrome doesn't redraw page when needed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've searched SO for similar issues (e.x. [Chrome does not redraw <div> after it is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002195/chrome-does-not-redraw-div-after-it-is-hidden) and [Force DOM redraw/refresh on Chrome/Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac) ) but none of questions gave me the solution to my problem. I am writing modem configuration panel, the webpage with ,,tabs''. On every tab there are some settings-just like configuration panel of any router.

Saving configuration (done when user clicks on Save button) takes few seconds (my embedded platform is not a speed king), so I decided to put special PLEASE WAIT window (div to be precise) which is usually hidden, but is shown when needed to calm user down :-).

**Everything works fine on Firefox**: after clicking save, the PLEASE WAIT div shows and then the configuration is saved using POST method. **However, on Chrome 26 and Chromium 25 the div does not show until the configuration is saved**. As you can see in `SaveConfiguration` function after executing PHP script that saves configuration the alert is shown-this is where the PLEASE WAIT div shows up on Chrome. **It looks like Chrome is not redrawing page but immediately starts launching POST script. Has anyone had similar issues and now how to fix this problem?**

Below are fragments of my code, I have only supplied functions that might give a clue what I'm doing. I can post more code if that helps.

```
function showLoadingScreen(yes)
{
    if(yes)
    {
        document.getElementById("loadingtext").innerHTML="Please wait...";
        document.getElementById("loading_overlay").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("loading_window").style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("loading_overlay").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("loading_window").style.display="none";
    }
}

function postDataSync(url, params)
{
    var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else 
        if (window.ActiveXObject) 
        {
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new
            ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
        }
    if(XMLHttpRequestObject) 
    {
        XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", url, false);
        XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        XMLHttpRequestObject.send(params);
        {
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
            XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) 
            {
                var result = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                delete XMLHttpRequestObject;
                XMLHttpRequestObject = null;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return '';  
}

function SaveConfiguration()
{
    var errors=checkForm();
    if(errors!="")
    {
        printError("Can't save configuration because there are errors in current tab:<br><br>"+errors);
        return;
    }
    showLoadingScreen(true);
    saveTab();
    var retval=postDataSync('actions/saveconf3.php','');
    alert("Settings saved. The modem is now being reconfigured.");
    document.location = "http://" + retval;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ajax synchronously rather than asynchronously meaning javascript execution halts during the request. To fix make the following change:

```
XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", url, true);
```

You need to use a callback for the behaviour after the request is complete. Something like this:

```
    function postDataSync(url, params, success)
    {
        var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else 
            if (window.ActiveXObject) 
            {
                XMLHttpRequestObject = new
                ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
            }
        if(XMLHttpRequestObject) 
        {
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", url, true);
            XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            XMLHttpRequestObject.send(params);
            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
                XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) 
                {

    var result = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                    delete XMLHttpRequestObject;
                    XMLHttpRequestObject = null;
                    if (typeof success === 'function') success(result);
                }
            }
        }
        return '';  
    }

function SaveConfiguration()
{
    var errors=checkForm();
    if(errors!="")
    {
        printError("Can't save configuration because there are errors in current tab:<br><br>"+errors);
        return;
    }
    showLoadingScreen(true);
    saveTab();
    postDataSync('actions/saveconf3.php','', saveComplete);
}

function saveComplete(result) {
  showLoadingScreen(false);
  alert("Settings saved. The modem is now being reconfigured.");
  document.location = "http://" + result;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not solve the issue. Notice that I launch function showing please wait BEFORE executing ajax request, so the JS execution can be stopped during request. It looks like Chrome is somehow... prefetching the request?

Secondly, if I launch request asynchronously then the alert telling user that Settings are saved is useless because it shows before the request is finished.

Comment: No chrome is not prefetching the request, it's just that it doesn't action the style changes until the current javascript execution has finished (the javascript and rendering parts of the browser take turns). I'm just about to edit my answer to explain how you solve the second issue...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you haven't change false to true in open in function-it should be true for async ajax call am I right?

Comment: @Wookie88 - Oops! Cut and paste error! There was another error in that I was neglecting the return value (it needs to be fed into the callback rather than returned). Now fixed

Comment: Another error found: The code below XMLHttpRequestObject.send should be put in XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechanged = function () { ... }. Anyway, BIG +1 for you Sir :) because've helped me alot - I've also learned async request + callback practice which looks very elegant for me.

Comment: Your suggested edit has been rejected... but not by me (I don't have enough reputation to reject edits). However, for what it's worth, you're absolutely correct and there clearly is a line missing from my code. I'll edit it myself so that it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you have heavy synchronous code (in practice, operations on hundreds or thousands of objects that are already in memory, or calculating pi to a gazillion digits) you can use `setTimeout` to give the browser time to catch up with any rendering tasks. You'd either need to call `setTimeout` for each task, or if you have a long-running task, split it up in batches first. This requires quite a bit of refactoring though, since every task needs to be represented as a function that can be passed to `setTimeout.`

I wouldn't use XMLHTTPRequest synchronously ever.

If `setTimeout(fn, 0)` does not trigger the "incremental" rendering, try a higher value, until it works. I think I needed to use a value of 100ms between jobs in some cases, for some browsers (I don't recall which).

You may need to yield to the browser even quicker if you want to achieve 60fps, or 30fps. Then you need to stay under 16ms or 33ms for each task. That gets very tight on slow hardware, such as (older types of) smartphones. Then, instead of `setTimeout`, you can best use `requestAnimationFrame`, if available.

Comment: If you want the max frame rate then window.requestAnimationFrame(fn) is the way to go as that is what it's for (at least on modern browsers). However, I think doing it asynchronously and using a callback is more common (and probably simpler) way of approaching this problem.

Comment: RobJ, you're absolutely right. I'll update my answer. It's just that when I said that it only applied to "heavy processing" I realized it didn't. It depends on your performance needs. It's yielding to the browser that's important, and that's what requestAnimationFrame allows one to do.